# How can I make VS Code display a file in a two editor groups, where the bottom line of the left group is always the top of the right one?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I split an editor in VS Code, it gives a copy of opened file.
Is there is a plugin which makes second window display rest of opening file. How can I make it so that the scrolling of those two editor tabs for the same file is synced together, and that the bottom code line shown in the left-side editor group tab is synced to the top code line of the right-side editor group tab?

I want this because it would help me to read lengthy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [the under-scroll extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GiorgosXou.under-scroll).